# Iterate over 2D numpy array to find corresponding maximum values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I have a set of data as such:

```
interactions=np.array([[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2,5], [2,7]])
```

I need to iterate over each value in the first column, find the corresponding maximum value in the second column and then store in a new array (or delete the other values from this array). For this example the final output would therefore be:

```
interactions=[[0, 3], [1, 4], [2,7]]
```

I have managed to write a piece of code that will do this for a specific column value, but can't work out how to turn it into a loop to do the whole array:

Create an array to store values in:

```
p_gamma=np.amax(interactions[:,0])
zfinal=np.zeros([np.int(p_gamma)+1, 2])
```

Find the maximum value for each column value (this is where I need the help!):

```
counter=0
interactions=interactions[interactions[:,0] ==counter]
maxval=np.amax(interactions[:, 1])
interactions=interactions[interactions[:, 1] == maxval]
zfinal[0,:]=interactions
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!!!

Comment: Are the "index" (first column) values necessarily sorted (as in your example)?

Comment: Yes, the first column is in ascending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numpy` method for this would be:

```
i = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(interactions[:, 0])) + 1   # finding indices where first column changes
np.maximum.reduceat(interactions, np.r_[0, i])        # taking maximum values between those indices

array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! All my values are positive so would I need the np.flatnonzero term?

Comment: Yes.  `flatnonzero` is looking for indices, not values.  They will always be positive anyway.

Comment: @DanielF like the answer for a pure numpy method. upvote.

Comment: @ehsan if the indices hadn't been sorted I probably would have recommended a `pandas` `groupby` solution along the lines of your answer, although sorting the array first and staying in `numpy` is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas groupby first column `0` and take max and convert back to numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(interactions).groupby(0).max().reset_index().to_numpy()
```

output:

```
[[0 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 7]]
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `pd.DataFrame(interactions)`: create a data frame from numpy array
- `groupby(0)`: groups data by first column
- `max()`: find maximum of second column within each group
- `reset_index()`: convert groupby object to dataframe
- `to_numpy()`: convert dataframe to numpy array

Comment: Hi thanks for this! Could you explain to me what the code is doing please?

Comment: @okvoyce added explanation to the post. Hope it helps clarify the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible one line solution without using any additional library:

```
result = list(zip(np.unique(interactions[:,0]),
                  map(max, np.split(interactions[:,1], 
                                    np.unique(interactions[:,0], 
                                              return_index=True)[1][1:]))))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 7)]
```